# Laravel Video, Audio and image upload

Tags: php, laravel, upload

This is my image upload method of PostsController

```
public function store(Request $request, User $user, Image $image)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        'body' => 'required'
    ]);


    if( $request->hasFile('image') ) {
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

        Image::make($image)->save( public_path('uploads/images/' . $filename ) );
    } 

    $image = $filename;

    auth()->user()->publish(
        new Post(['body' => request('body'), 'image' => $image, 'user_id' => auth()->id()])
    );

    return redirect('/');
}
```

I want one method to upload image, video and audio as well with one input that user can upload image or video or audio
How can i do all these things in one controller?

Comment: Just change your validation rule to allow video and audio files as well?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Can you please tell me rules for video and audio

Comment: Instead of me reinventing the wheel here, I recommend that you do some research. I quick google on "laravel validation rules upload video audio" gave me a bunch of hits.

Answer (score 1):

First determine the whether the file is a video, audio or image. Then decide how you validate. Hope this will help.

```html
if( $request->hasFile('file') ) {
  $file = $request->file('file');
  $imagemimes = ['image/png']; //Add more mimes that you want to support
  $videomimes = ['video/mp4']; //Add more mimes that you want to support
  $audiomimes = ['audio/mpeg']; //Add more mimes that you want to support

  if(in_array($file->getMimeType() ,$imagemimes)) {
   $filevalidate = 'required|mimes:jpeg|max:2048';
  }
  //Validate video
  if (in_array($file->getMimeType() ,$videomimes)) {
   $filevalidate = 'required|mimes:mp4';
  }
  //validate audio
  if (in_array($file->getMimeType() ,$audiomimes)) {
   $filevalidate = 'required|mimes:mpeng';
  }  
    }
    $this->validate($request, [
        'file' => $filevalidate,
        'body' => 'required'
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using form requests, try with below code

```
  public function rules() {
    $rules = [
        'some_field' => 'required',
    ];

    //  if fileType is audio
    if ($this->input('fileType') == 'audio') {
        $rules['file'] = 'mimes:mp3,mp4';
    }

    //if fileType is video
    if ($this->input('fileType') == 'video') {
         $rules['file'] = 'mimes:mp4,3gp';

    }
    return $rules;
}
```

field names and validation rules change as per your requirement.